# Calculate sum based on the comparison of key in Object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this below array of objects, where the schedule number are stored

```
const initialObj = [
    {
        index: 9417,
        schudule_number: '11010'
    },
    {
        index: 8427,
        schudule_number: '11020'
    }
];
```

This is the expected output i needed :

```
const finalOutput = [
    {
        index: 9417,
        schudule_number: '11010',
        adjustedAmount: [ {key:"Labour Cost",value:11},{key:"Material Cost",value:0} ]
    },
    {
        index: 8427,
        schudule_number: '11020',
        adjustedAmount: [ {key:"Labour Cost",value:6},{key:"Material Cost",value:2} ]
    }
];
```

Here is the adjustedAmount array of objects, using this i am calculating the sum of each values :

```
const amount = [{
      adjustedAmount: '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":1},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}]',
      schudule_number: '11010'
  },
  {
      adjustedAmount: '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":10},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}]',
      schudule_number: '11010'
  },
  {
      adjustedAmount: '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":1},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}]',
      schudule_number: '11020'
  },
  {
      adjustedAmount: '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":5},{"key":"Material Cost","value":2}]',
      schudule_number: '11020'
  }
];
```

Code to calculate the sum of each values, but it does not compare the schedule numbers

```
const sumResults = 
  Object.entries(amount)
    .map(x => JSON.parse(x.adjustedAmount))
    .flatMap(x => [...x])
    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (acc[curr.key]) {
        acc[curr.key] += curr.value;
      } else {
        acc[curr.key] = curr.value;
      }
      return acc;
    }, {}))
    .map(([key, value]) => ({
      key,
      value
    }));
```

And finally to merge the array of objects

```
initialObj.forEach(va => {
  va["adjustedAmount"] = sumResults;
});
```

How do i compare the schedule number and insert into the initialObj ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you start out by building up a simple map of your `amount` data:

```
const amountMap = amount.reduce((acc, a) => {
    const item = acc[a.schudule_number];
    const obj = JSON.parse(a.adjustedAmount).reduce( (obj,i) => ({...obj, [i.key]:i.value}),{});
    if(item){
      Object.entries(obj).forEach( ([k,v]) => item[k] += v);
    }
    else{
      acc[a.schudule_number] = obj;
    }
    return acc;
},{});
```

Then the code to bring it into your `finalOutput` is really quite simple:

```
const finalOutput = initialObj.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  adjustedAmount: Object.entries(amountMap[o.schudule_number]).map( ([k,v]) => ({key:k,value:v}))
}))
```

Live example below:

```js
const initialObj = [
    {
        index: 9417,
        schudule_number: '11010'
    },
    {
        index: 8427,
        schudule_number: '11020'
    }
];
const amount = [{
      adjustedAmount: '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":1},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}]',
      schudule_number: '11010'
  },
  {
      adjustedAmount: '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":10},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}]',
      schudule_number: '11010'
  },
  {
      adjustedAmount: '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":1},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}]',
      schudule_number: '11020'
  },
  {
      adjustedAmount: '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":5},{"key":"Material Cost","value":2}]',
      schudule_number: '11020'
  }
]

const amountMap = amount.reduce((acc, a) => {
    const item = acc[a.schudule_number];
    const obj = JSON.parse(a.adjustedAmount).reduce( (obj,i) => ({...obj, [i.key]:i.value}),{});
    if(item){
      Object.entries(obj).forEach( ([k,v]) => item[k] += v);
    }
    else{
      acc[a.schudule_number] = obj;
    }
    return acc;
},{});




const finalOutput = initialObj.map(o => ({
  ...o,
  adjustedAmount: Object.entries(amountMap[o.schudule_number]).map( ([k,v]) => ({key:k,value:v}))
}))
console.log(finalOutput);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const amount = [
  {
    adjustedAmount:
      '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":1},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}]',
    schudule_number: "11010",
  },
  {
    adjustedAmount:
      '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":10},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}]',
    schudule_number: "11010",
  },
  {
    adjustedAmount:
      '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":1},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}]',
    schudule_number: "11020",
  },
  {
    adjustedAmount:
      '[{"key":"Labour Cost","value":5},{"key":"Material Cost","value":2}]',
    schudule_number: "11020",
  },
];

const initialObj = [
  {
    index: 9417,
    schudule_number: "11010",
  },
  {
    index: 8427,
    schudule_number: "11020",
  },
];

const result = initialObj.map((el) => {
  const { index, schudule_number } = el;
  const amountArray = amount.filter(
    (o) => o.schudule_number === schudule_number
  );
  const adjustedAmount = amountArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    const adjustedAmountArray = JSON.parse(curr.adjustedAmount);

    adjustedAmountArray.forEach(({ key, value }) => {
      const findEl = acc.find((o) => o.key === key);
      if (!findEl) acc.push({ key, value });
      else findEl.value += value;
    });
    return acc;
  }, []);

  return { index, schudule_number, adjustedAmount };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this using a simple map & reduce. Using `map`, each entry in the `initialObj` is mapped by finding the entry in the second array and merging it using `reduce`:

```js
const initialObj = [{ index: 9417, schudule_number: '11010' },{index: 8427, schudule_number: '11020'}];
const amount = [{adjustedAmount: [{"key":"Labour Cost","value":1},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}], schudule_number: '11010'},{ adjustedAmount: [{"key":"Labour Cost","value":10},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}], schudule_number: '11010' },{adjustedAmount: [{"key":"Labour Cost","value":1},{"key":"Material Cost","value":0}], schudule_number: '11020' },{ adjustedAmount: [{"key":"Labour Cost","value":5},{"key":"Material Cost","value":2}], schudule_number: '11020'}];

const transform = (obj1, obj2) => {
  return obj1.map(e => {
    const merged = obj2
        .filter(o => o.schudule_number === e.schudule_number)
        .reduce((r, {adjustedAmount}) => {
           adjustedAmount.forEach(amt => {
            const obj = r.find(o => o.key === amt.key);
            if(!obj){ r.push(amt);}
            else{ obj.value += amt.value;}
           });
           return r;
        }, []);
     e.adjustedAmount = merged;
     return e;
  });
}

console.log(transform(initialObj, amount));
```